# Windows 10 keyboard shutdown trigger

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

I have been experiencing a strange issue causing my computer to shutdown when pressing the following key combination “awe”.

I am completely puzzled by this and can not find any hints or users running into a similar issue. Regardless of which app is active, if I press “awe” on its own, without <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or the Windows key, the computer immediately triggers a shutdown event.

I am running windows 10 and do not have any user defined hot keys.

Comment: Is any kind of AutoHotKey script running?

Comment: I don’t recall enabling any script, how can I check what AutoHotKeu scripts are running? I am transitioning from Mac to Windows, so my knowledge is somewhat limited regarding windows customizations.

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s12

I see how this works now. I am going to try remapping the awe key combination using AutoHotKey. 
I will report back, but would like to know if someone has a more in depth understanding of why this is happening.

Comment: I can't write autohotkey script for you in the comments, should I write in answer?